# Create date-based folders with sieve

Tags: dovecot, sieve

I'd like to archive messages by year, perhaps month.
I can create a new rule each month, but I'd rather do it automatically.

Move all messages to a folder called `ARCHIVE/%y/%m` or something like it.

I'd prefer to use the webinterface to sieve provided by roundcube, but I can access the server if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't expect you can do this through Roundcube's web interface, but here's a solution for manually writing Sieve scripts. Moving into date-based folders is possible by combining several sieve extensions: `fileinto`, [`date`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5260) and [`mailbox`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5490#section-3).

```
require ["fileinto", "date", "mailbox"]
```

Put the current date into variables:

```
if currentdate :matches "year" "*" { set "year" "${1}"; }
if currentdate :matches "month" "*" { set "month" "${1}"; }
```

And to file the message, run:

```
fileinto :create "Archive.${year}.${month}"
```

Depending on your IMAP path settings, you might require `/` instead of `.`. `:create` enables creation of folders if they do not exist yet.